# User input from a Python List and assigning into variable

Tags: python, list, drop-down-menu

I am creating a program in which user will choose a state name from drop down menu, and the assigned number will get be selected in my variable. How do I do it?

```
[(1, 'Andaman and Nicobar Islands'), (2, 'Andhra Pradesh'), (3, 'Arunachal Pradesh'), (4, 'Assam'), (5, 'Bihar'), (6, 'Chandigarh'), (7, 'Chhattisgarh'), (8, 'Dadra and Nagar Haveli'), (37, 'Daman and Diu'), (9, 'Delhi'), (10, 'Goa'), (11, 'Gujarat'), (12, 'Haryana'), (13, 'Himachal Pradesh'), (14, 'Jammu and Kashmir'), (15, 'Jharkhand'), (16, 'Karnataka'), (17, 'Kerala'), (18, 'Ladakh'), (19, 'Lakshadweep'), (20, 'Madhya Pradesh'), (21, 'Maharashtra'), (22, 'Manipur'), (23, 'Meghalaya'), (24, 'Mizoram'), (25, 'Nagaland'), (26, 'Odisha'), (27, 'Puducherry'), (28, 'Punjab'), (29, 'Rajasthan'), (30, 'Sikkim'), (31, 'Tamil Nadu'), (32, 'Telangana'), (33, 'Tripura'), (34, 'Uttar Pradesh'), (35, 'Uttarakhand'), (36, 'West Bengal')]
```

I am just able to access the elements.

```
print(list1[0][0])
```

Comment: By *dropdown-menu* are you going to implement it in tkinter

Comment: And ...```print(list[0][0])``` is a serious mistake. You just shadowed the ```list``` function

Comment: My question is not about drop down menu, but about accessing states name and their number from the list and putting them in a variable for further use in the program.

Comment: Hi @Sujay I just showed the `list[0][0]` for representation and not for actual use.

Comment: Don't call your list list! `my_list = [('a', 1), ('b', 2)]`, then `print(my_list[0][0])` yields `a`

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Dictionary` for this. Store the state name as `key` and code as `value`.

```
state_names =  {'Andaman and Nicobar Islands': 1, 'Andhra Pradesh': 2, 'Arunachal Pradesh': 3, 'Assam': 4, 'Bihar': 5, 'Chandigarh': 6, 'Chhattisgarh': 7, 'Dadra and Nagar Haveli': 8, 'Daman and Diu': 37, 'Delhi': 9, 'Goa': 10, 'Gujarat': 11, 'Haryana': 12, 'Himachal Pradesh': 13, 'Jammu and Kashmir': 14, 'Jharkhand': 15, 'Karnataka': 16, 'Kerala': 17, 'Ladakh': 18, 'Lakshadweep': 19, 'Madhya Pradesh': 20, 'Maharashtra': 21, 'Manipur': 22, 'Meghalaya': 23, 'Mizoram': 24, 'Nagaland': 25, 'Odisha': 26, 'Puducherry': 27, 'Punjab': 28, 'Rajasthan': 29, 'Sikkim': 30, 'Tamil Nadu': 31, 'Telangana': 32, 'Tripura': 33, 'Uttar Pradesh': 34, 'Uttarakhand': 35, 'West Bengal': 36}
```

To get the code of a state - `state_names['Goa']` gives `10`.

Comment: And to convert the existing list of tuples into that dictionary, do this: `dict1 = {v: k for (k,v) in list1}`